# Non-Visual Studio alternative to Active Template Library (ATL)

Tags: windows, library, c++, visual-studio

I have some Windows C++ code that needs to interoperate with COM objects. I'd like to avoid the headache of accessing COM directly (manipulating reference counts, etc.), but I'd also like to avoid writing something that only works in Visual C++.

Are there any C++ libraries like ATL that aren't Visual Studio-specific?

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) for the C#/.COM side of things.

- Cross Platform
- Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework
- based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime.

Comment: Thanks, but at the moment, I'm looking specifically for C++ support.